# Run a foreground command in a new terminal tab

Tags: bash

I need to run 2 foreground processes in cmd.
Is there a simple way to automatize the task and run a command in a new tab via bash script?

Comment: What's a "tab" in this context?  What terminal program are you using?

Comment: the default terminal in ubuntu (or even terminator). By tab in this context I mean open a new "tab" with another terminal in the same window.